# how to associate model with LDAP authenticated user?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ldap, asp.net-mvc-5

I have almost no experience with APS.net. I am creating a website that will use LDAP as authentication. Login is already working using  but I need to be able to relate LDAP users to records in the database. I need to be able to store information like who created the record(logged in user) and relate the record to other users based on LDAP groups/roles. I am using the Entity Framework. I have experience with Doctrine2 from php so I am making assumptions that the Entity Framework works similarly to Droctrine2.

1) What information about an LDAP user should I use as an identifier? How can I retrieve it for the logged in User?

2)Do I store the LDAP user identifier directly on the model and then query LDAP to get information about the user or is there someway to associate a model to a LDAP user using that identifier magically making an instance of some class representing the LDAP user?

[UDPATE]

This is an internal website. Only Active Directory users should be able to log in.
Thank you.

Comment: The quickest way to do this is to authenticate your users against your provider like Active Directory, if it checks out then get the user from your application's DB. This is obviously some duplication of users and roles but is actually more flexible because it will allow for external users to signup and use your service. If you are interested in an enterprise solution that doesn't duplicate then you need to look at FIM

Comment: @Shoe Good suggestion. I am creating an internal website so this is not applicable. Only users in Active Directory should be able to access this website. Users won't be able to sign up through the website. I would like to avoid storing information about the users in the site's database besides an identifer(id?).

Comment: What about just a stub table containing the users name and the active directory `EmployeeId`. Then you can link that table to your other ones. A potential problem with this is that if your AD user gets deleted your application will not.

Comment: @Shoe That was my initial thought. But as you have mentioned I would have to take care of synchronizing users and I would like to avoid that as much as possible.

Comment: It's only a problem if the data should go away when the user is deleted. A lot of applications will want to keep that data around for auditing or for record keeping.

Comment: @Shoe If i decide to go this route, how do you suggest to handle the creation of the stub table's records. Is it possible to create some sort of Listener that attaches after the LDAP user is authenticated? Or maybe have active directory fire some sort of event when a new user is created. What do you think is best?

Comment: What I would do is first authenticate with AD. If it's successful you know it's a good user. Check to see if they exist in the system. If they don't then add them else do nothing. This way your system auto-generates your users.